# Translation for LWC/Aura component in Experience Cloud

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, aura, lightning-community, experience-cloud

What is the best approach to translate a LWC or Aura in Experience Cloud?

Is it possible to use the OOTB Export Content of Experience cloud for translation of custom components? I have tried this but the export does not contain any label or text present in the component.

If not this, is creating custom labels for translation only the viable option left?

Answer (score 0):

Yes Custom Labels is the way to go for translation, doesn't matter in which context you are.

The export of translation from the Experience Builder is for everything which is configured through the Experience Builder like parameters sent to components (content of rich text component for example) and predefined Salesforce values like menu item labels.